# How to return the Celery task to the queue that it could take another worker?

Tags: celery

Sometimes, it is required that the worker is, after taking the job, it is not processed, and returned back to the turn to the other worker is able to pick up and handle it. How to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to mid-execution crashes, you can turn on the `CELERY_ACKS_LATE` configuration.
Keep in mind that it may have some side effects as described [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#faq-acks-late-vs-retry)